# Implementing polling for Rails Frontend to call update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, polling

I want to implement a system where my 'show' view, every 10 seconds will call update in the controller, then asynchronously updates the view without refreshing the page.

I have it at the point where it updates asynchronously. However I need to get it polling.

My approach is:

- controller show action responds with JS

  ```
  def show
      @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
  end
  ```
- Then JS that does somthing like this..

`

```
// starts the polling on page load
$(function() {
    setTimeout(callUpdate, 10000);
});

// Continues to poll, making ajax calls 
function callUpdate() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("update")) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/simulations/<%= @simulation.id %>"
      });
    } else {
      alert("An error occured updating record.");
    }
    $('#sim_div').html("<%= j (render @simulation) %>");
    setTimeout(callUpdate, 10000);
}
```

What the correct way of doing this? I've tried using coffeescript in the assets, but it is called on every controller element, I've tried embedding it in the html or trying to include it as a partial but I either get issues with rendering the ruby code I need too, or not getting access to enough of it, I've tried doing `respond_to` but it only gives me html. Can anyone help me solve this?

Edit:

Here is my show view:

```
<%= render 'simulation' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', simulations_path %>
```

and the included partial :

```
<div id="sim_div">
  <h1><%= @simulation.identifier %></h1>
  <h4 class="offset-col-sm-1">Dimensions: <%= @simulation.x_size %>x<%= @simulation.y_size %></h4>
  <h4 class="offset-col-sm-1">Verdict: <%= @simulation.verdict %></h4>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @simulation.state.each do |row| %>
        <tr>
        <% row.each do |current| %>        
            <td class="text-center"><%= current %></td>        
          <% end%>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be this:

```js
$.ajax({ method: "PUT", url: $(".some-element").data("url") })
.done(function(data) {
  //here you can use the new data
});
```

Changes are that you have an element with class "some-element" with the attribute data-url set to the path that rails generate automatically for the update route. In your html you will have:

```html
<div class='some-element' data-url="<%= simulations_path(@simulation) %>">
  ...
</div>
```

In your controller you should return @simulation as json.

Other advantages of this solution is that you can avoid embedding ruby in javascript which implies that the server sends the file for every request.

The polling is right, but other ways to do it would be with web sockets. In Rails you have some gems to do that, and in the near future Rails 5 will come along with ActionCable. Anyway I would continue with polling since it is way simpler than websockets.

The way this solution works:

1. You request the show view and the server responds with the html, js and css files.
2. Polling starts and every 10 seconds a request is sent to simulations#update (simulations controller/update action).There you can update and save your simulation and return the new values.
3. In jquery's ajax.done you get the new data and you can update the client side data.

Hope it helps,

Santiago

Comment: Regularly in the polling two things need to happen: 1. update needs to be called, 2. the simulation needs to be re-rended with the updated, I dont understand how your solution does this or where the code would fit in (one big issues im stuck on is just where to put the javascript) would you be able to extrapolate a bit more? I'm a bit confused by your answer still, however Im by no means asking for all the code written.

Comment: The javascript just put it in a file under app/assets/javascripts/ . You can call it the way you want, for example `simulation.js`. The way it works is like this:
1. You request the show view and you get the html, js and css files to the client side.
2. Polling starts and every 10 seconds it sends a get request to the server where you can do whatever you want and respond with the new data.
3. You get the new data inside the `jquery get` function and you update your html.

Comment: So where would the update call sit? I havn't gotten it to work right anywhere so far.

Comment: Ok I was confused about what you wanted to do. The update call is done in the polling by the ajax request, and there you update models or whatever you want and then you send back to the client the new data and update the view with this data.