# Using data retrieved via polling in Rails view

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, polling

In an effort to understand Javascript short polling, I am trying to create a simple page with a list of comments. The Rails view will poll the server for any updates (new comments), and keep updating the page accordingly.

So far I have managed to use `setTimeout` to get requests sent to the server every 3 seconds (which I can see because I get an alert every 3 seconds).

But how do I feed this information back to the view, or more specifically, how do I replace the `@comments` that are rendered with the new list of comments that I got back in the response?

```html
<!-- index.html.erb -->
<h1>List of comments</h1>

<div id="comments">
  <%= render @comments %>
</div>

<script>
function reloadComments() {
  $.get('/', function(data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data.comments + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
  setTimeout(reloadComments, 3000);
}

// Trigger after loading the page
$(function() {
  setTimeout(reloadComments, 3000);
});
</script>
```

```html
<!--_comment.html.erb-->
<div class="comment">
  <p><%= comment.content %></p>
</div>
```

The controller method that is called with the HTTP GET call returns all the comments as a JSON like this:

```rb
def show
  @comments = Comment.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { comments: @comments } }
    format.html
  end
end
```

I think my question is similar to this one, but it was never answered satisfactorily: [Implementing polling for Rails Frontend to call update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31952173/11249670)

Also, I'm aware that polling may not be the best solution for near-real-time updates (I know about websockets). Since this app is just for POC, I'm not worried about making too many requests to the server.

Thank you!

Ruby version: 2.6.3
Rails version: 6.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions to your problem:

**1. Render a `js.erb` template from your server**

A `js.erb` file contains javascript code that will we sent from the server and executed on the frontend.

Simply put, instead of rendering classic HTML, the server will send back the javascript code you write in your `js.erb` file. The advantage of such an approach is that you can use ruby in your template and render your comments html instead of building it from scratch. (see the link to the rails docs below for more details)

In your controller:

```rb
def show
  @comments = Comment.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

In your `views/comments/show.js.erb` file (which will be render by the server):

```
$("#comments").html('<%= j render @comments %>')
```

In your view `view/comments/show.html.erb`

```
function reloadComments() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/comments',
    dataType: 'script'
  })
}

// Trigger after loading the page
$(function() {
  setTimeout(reloadComments, 3000);
});
```

[More info in Rails docs here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns)

**2. Build the HTML template from your json data in your frontend javascript**

I won't put the code here but there's plenty of resources online and this is not the simplest approach regarding your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm sorry, I am new to Ajax/erb etc. and don't quite get your answer. But I've come to realise that trying to update the @comments variable via Ajax is probably not the wisest way, and am trying to work on an alternative solution.

Comment: Hey Risa, I've added more details to my answer. Basically, you make a datascript request to your rails server, which will render the matchin js.erb file according to rails conventions. What you write in this file (here we just render @comments and replace it in the view) will be executed in the frontend once the request ends.